# How to reduce renders using redux + normalizr

Tags: performance, reactjs, redux, react-redux, normalizr

I have an app using React + Redux + Normalizr, I would like to know the best practices to reduce the number of renders when something changes on `entities`.

Right if I change just one entity inside the entities, it will re-render all the components and not only the components that need that specific entity

Comment: Normally, React Shadow DOM only updates what truly changed, even though all `render()` methods are called in order to compute it. It should stay pretty fast. Do you have any profiled performances issues?

Comment: Anyways, you can take a look a the `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method to reduce the number of render computations.

Comment: [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) will help you in some situation.

Comment: this comment explain a little bit better - https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/991#issuecomment-205895654

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several things you can do to minimize the number of renders in your app, and make updates faster.
Let's look at them from your Redux store down to your React components.

- **In your Redux store**, you can use immutable data structures (for example, [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)). This will make all subsequent optimizations faster, as you'll be able to compare changes by only checking for previous/next state slice equality rather than recursively comparing all props.
- **In your containers**, that is in your top-level components where you inject redux state as props, ask only for the state slices you need, and use the `pure` [option](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md) (I assume you're using react-redux) to make sure your container will be re-rendered only if the state slices returned by your `mapStateToProps` functions have changed.
- **If you need to compute derived data**, that is if you inject in your containers data computed from various state slices, use a memoized function to make sure the computation is not triggered again if the input doesn't change, and to keep object equality with the value the previous call returned. [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) is a very good library to do that.
- **In your dumb components** use the `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle to avoid a re-render when incoming props do not change. If you do not want to implement this manually, you can use React's [PureRenderMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html) to check all props for you, or, for example, the `pure` function from the [Recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) library if you need more control. A good use case at this level is rendering a list of items. If your item component implements `shouldComponentUpdate` only the modified items will be re-rendered. But this shouldn't be a fix-all-problems habit : a good components separation is often preferable in that it makes flow props only to those components which will need them.

As far as Normalizr is concerned, there is nothing more specific to be done.

Comment: To help you decide where to optimize, Dan Abramov just said on Twitter (https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/719723513016426496): "component separation can make a much bigger difference than manual shouldComponentUpdate() everywhere", because "connect() from React Redux already takes care of shouldComponentUpdate() for most cases. Focus on finding the optimal component separation".

Comment: @pierrepinard_2 many thanks for the heads-up! I've edited the answer to include that remark

Comment: Regarding first item. Can you provide an example of immutable + redux store?

Comment: @rat well let's say you have a `people` reducer with the following structure : `{1: {name: 'John', status: 'admin'}, {2: {name: 'Jack', status: 'user'}}`, you could make it an immutable map of immutable maps. Updating one person like so : `return state.setIn([1, 'status'], 'user')` would return a new object for `people`, a new object for `people.get(1)` but the same object as before for `people.get(2)`

Comment: @VonD thank you. Very helpful. We have this logic (map logic) running in the connect. It doesn't seems to work as expected. I'm somewhat concerned to use this in the redux store, since is not a state its actually derived data.

Comment: @VonD .. but I'll run some tests with your redux+immutable idea

Answer (score 1):

If in some case (it should be rare) you detect performance problems that are directly related to React's rendering cycles of components, then you should implement the **shouldComponentUpdate()** method in the involved components (details can be found in React's docs [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html)).

Change-detection in shouldComponentUpdate() will be particularly easy because Redux forces you to implement immutable state:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

    return nextProps.dataObject !== this.props.dataObject;

    // true when dataObject has become a new object,
    // which happens if (and only if) its data has changed,
    // thanks to immutability
}
```

Comment: could you address this comment - https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/991#issuecomment-205895654?

Comment: At least for me this solely works if you're using trivial data. When you use derived data (for example form reselect) the inequality above will not work as expected